# How to Translate this LINQ Query to use Lambda Expressions Instead?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

**i want this bellow syntax write by using the lambda expression**

```
  from p in this.Context.tblUserInfos
                where p.Status == 1
                select new {p.UserID,p.UserName,p.tblUserType.UserType };
```

suppose i write

```
this.Context.tblUserInfos.Where(p => p.Status == 1);
```

How to write the above syntax by using the => operator.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it desirable to switch to the lambda format?

Comment: Because its more geeky!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you already have the where portion of it in there so I am assuming you only need the select:

```
this.Context.tblUserInfos
            .Where(p => p.Status == 1)
            .Select(p => new { p.UserID, p.UserName, p.tblUserType.UserType });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.Context.tblUserInfos.Where(p => p.Status == 1)
            .Select(p => new { p.UserID, p.UserName, p.tblUserType.UserType });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.Select` **IEnumerable** extension method to *project* the result set into an anonymous type.

Like this:

```
var someAnonymousType = this.Context.tblUserInfos
                             .Where(p => p.Status == 1)
                             .Select(p => new {p.UserID,p.UserName,p.tblUserType.UserType };);
```

Answer (score 1):

[LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) can convert queries between LINQ and lambda syntax